# PFUser.logOut() not working?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, logout

I have a MMDrawerViewController in which the left TableViewController has a row to log out. The following are my codes for this cell:

```
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch(indexPath.row){

    case 4:

    PFUser.logOut()

    let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController

    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController

    break

    default:
    print("\(menuItems[indexPath.row])is selected")

    }
```

I tapped the log out row and the loginViewController did show up. However when i run the app again (when the user should be logged out already), the centerViewController, instead of the loginViewController, shows up instead. Any idea why this is happening? I'm very new to swift so hope I'm explaining everything alright, thanks!

Comment: Have u import Parse in current ViewController?

Comment: Are you saying every time you run your app it starts at the table VC rather than the login VC? That might be your storyboard setup if this is the issue. Please elaborate a bit more on the correct flow.

Comment: yes i have imported parse for all my viewControllers

Comment: indeed, every time i run the app, it starts at the table VC. I have checked the storyboard, my loginViewController is my initial VC. Basically, I want the app to start at the tableVC if logged in; and start at loginVC if logged out.

Comment: guys thanks for the replies! just figured it out! turns out PFUser.enableAutomaticUser() is on, so thats why currentUser will never be == nil thanks anyways!